# Changes in Transform property in Mui Theme not getting reflected on browser

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make changes to the MuiInputLabel.outlined. Although, I can see other changes when I inspect on browser, I'm not particularly able to see the transform property change.

This is my MuiInputLabel.

```
MuiInputLabel: {
  outlined: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    zIndex: 1,
    transform: 'translate(-4,8), scale(1)',
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  },
```

And this is when I inspect on browser:

[image: Inspected]

Answer (score 0):

this is not the right way to add multiple `transform` property in css. There shouldn't be `,` in the `transform` style. And also transform value needs a unit like `px`, `em` and others.
The right way is:-

`transform: 'translate(-4px ,8px) scale(1)'`

Comment: I removed the comma but it still gets striked down.